# how to get the actual zoom of WheelZoomTool in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

```
class ZoomLevelGetter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.currentBokehObject = figure(
                title="Plot",
                plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
                x_axis_label='Time', y_axis_label='Value',
                tools=["pan", "wheel_zoom", hoverTool, "reset"],
                active_drag="pan",
                active_scroll="wheel_zoom")
        self.currentZoom = 1.0

    def zoom_changed(self):
        # i want here to get a new zoom of "wheel_zoom" tool to self.currentZoom
        self.currentZoom = #new zoom#
```

I want to get a zoom level of WheelZoom tool. But as I saw - there is no satisfaying property to get in this tool.

1. Where can I get the zoom ( I think that the zoom is not only the float that applied to axises )?
2. How can I get it like an event that may call my python function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to get the current zoom percentage however, we can calculate it by using the x range and y range, for that first we need to bound the x and y axis to a specific or a relative value like max and min of x and y axis values we can also keep some offsets if we want, because bokeh chart has infinite property.

example

```
plot1 = figure()
x_range = plot1.x_range
x_start, x_end = x_range.start, x_range.end

y_range = plot1.y_range
y_start, y_end = y_range.start, y_range.end

x_zoom_percent = (x_end - x_start) / (max(x) - min(x)) * 100
y_zoom_percent = (y_end - y_start) / (max(y) - min(y)) * 100
```

For more details you can refer this link
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/interaction/js_callbacks/js_on_event.html#index-0

Comment: Thank you for tour answer. But still have a problem - the x_range (start, end tuples) and y_range keep the same whenever I am zooming, so the zoom_precent stays 100% all the time. What could it be?